# DateTime format in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET Core (.net framework 5.0, Visual studio 2019) &  want to set date format as yyyy-mm-dd. Here are my current code

Model =>

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-mm-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
```

(also tried with ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)

In view =>

```
 <input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" asp-format="{0:yyyy-mm-dd}"  />
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.DOB)
```

Tried both ways but still getting the mm/dd/yyyy format.What is wrong with the codes & what I can do ?

Comment: You can use `DisplayFormat` attribute and display data like `@Model.DOB` to display the  format you want. But for input element, you need change your local pc datetime format then it can works with the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the code below?

```
<input asp-for="DOB" class="form-control" asp-format="**@Model.DOB.ToString($"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")**">
```